# Chrome Error Message: You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --extensions-on-chrome-urls. Stability and security will suffer

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I open chrome I am getting the following error message:

```
You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --extensions-on-chrome-urls. Stability and security will suffer.
```

Any ideas? I've tried a uninstall/reinstall of the browser [Image here of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOncb.png)

Comment: In `chrome://flags/`, do you have enabled the option of "Extensions on chrome:// URLs"? Does it arrive when running Chrome in Incognito mode?

Comment: Have you tried removing the unsupported command-line flag?  Anyways updated your question to include the, value of the Command Line field, from `chrome://version`

Comment: I added an answer. Please consider accepting it (tick the V sign).

Comment: Done and accepted @harrymc. Thank for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To disable the option of `extensions-on-chrome-urls`, enter `chrome://flags/`
and enter `urls` in the search field. You will see this entry:

[image]

Disable this option and the warning will disappear.

Comment: Almost downvoted because it is profoundly infuriating to live in a world where this is the situation, but it's not really your fault for answering as much as it can be answered. Of course, to a user who actually intentionally with full awareness turned on this setting, "turn that setting back off" can't possibly be an acceptable answer, and it's profoundly frustrating that anyone just says "turn it off" without at least acknowledging "if you need/want that setting on, there's no way to make the error go away, sorry".

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It is already disabled and the warning still shows up

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu: The flags in `chrome://flags/` have only temporary validity and stop working when the feature they disable goes mainstream.